# sagemaker notebook instance lifecycle configuration add pip install

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I am running the following `pip install`, every time I launch my notebook instance.

```
!pip install torch
!pip install transformers
```

How do I add it to an existing life cycle configuration? Existing lifecycle configuration looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ex

# OVERVIEW
# This script stops a SageMaker notebook once it's idle for more than 1 hour (default time)
# You can change the idle time for stop using the environment variable below.
# If you want the notebook the stop only if no browsers are open, remove the --ignore-connections flag
#
# Note that this script will fail if either condition is not met
#   1. Ensure the Notebook Instance has internet connectivity to fetch the example config
#   2. Ensure the Notebook Instance execution role permissions to SageMaker:StopNotebookInstance to stop the notebook 
#       and SageMaker:DescribeNotebookInstance to describe the notebook.
#

# PARAMETERS
IDLE_TIME=3600

echo "Fetching the autostop script"
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/master/scripts/auto-stop-idle/autostop.py


echo "Detecting Python install with boto3 install"

# Find which install has boto3 and use that to run the cron command. So will use default when available
# Redirect stderr as it is unneeded
CONDA_PYTHON_DIR=$(source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv && which python)
if $CONDA_PYTHON_DIR -c "import boto3" 2>/dev/null; then
    PYTHON_DIR=$CONDA_PYTHON_DIR
elif /usr/bin/python -c "import boto3" 2>/dev/null; then
    PYTHON_DIR='/usr/bin/
```

I found this link: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/install-pip-package-all-environments/on-start.sh

however, I'd like to install multiple packages. where in the script can i add multiple `pip install` lines?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the issue here. Perhaps it's not even relevant anymore, but just in case this helps someone: remember you can install multiple packages in the same line; e.g. `pip install package1 package2`

But if you're looking to provision your SageMaker instance with multiple packages, you can create a bash script and then upload it to SageMaker via the console, like [this article shows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebook-lifecycle-config.html). Finally, you can create a new SageMaker notebook and specify the new start-up script by "changing the environment" as [this article explains](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-lcc-create-console.html#studio-lcc-create-console-step3) or leave this script by default.

However, if you're familiarised with Amazon CDK, then you can simply reuse [this sample](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-neptune-samples/blob/4a35a28fd1f466969f65727769ffa3cd7a7531c8/neptune-sagemaker/cdk/python/neptune-notebook/neptune_notebook/neptune_notebook_stack.py), where a SageMaker notebook is created with a Lifecycle bash script. In here, maybe after line 98, you could add your `pip install package1 package2`.

Hope this helps.